# Delete data in React using Firebase Cloud

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new React, Today, I using React and Firebase to display, add and delete data. I have some data get Firebase and display in cards. Now, I want delete some want card, but I don't know. You can tell me how do it? Maybe create "X" button in top-right and when click, it deleted.

[image]

This is code call lists

```
const ProjectList = ({projects}) => {
  return (
    <div className="project-list section">
      { projects && projects.map(project => {
        return (
          <Link to={'/project/' + project.id} key={project.id}>
            <ProjectSummary project={project} />
          </Link>
        )
      })}  
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is ProjectSummary

```
const ProjectSummary = ({project}) => {
  return (
    <div className="card z-depth-0 project-summary">
      <div className="card-content grey-text text-darken-3">
        <span className="card-title ">{project.title}</span>
        <p>Created by {project.authorFirstName} {project.authorLastName} admin</p>
        <p className="grey-text">{moment(project.createdAt.toDate()).calendar()}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And structure data in Firebase

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button for deleting in ProjectSummary list item like this

```
<button onClick={() => this.removeProject(project.id)}>Delete</button>
```

Id will be firebase unique key something like this ahakhka734hfakh3

Then in callback we can call firebase.database()'s remove method, which strips it from the page like this.

```
removeProject(projectId) {
  const projectRef= firebase.database().ref(`/projects/${projectId}`);
  projectRef.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like:

```
<button onClick={() => this.removeProject(project.id)}>Delete</button>

   removeProject(id) {
     firebase.delete({ collection: 'project', doc:`${id}` }).then((response) => {
        console.log('delete response', response)
     }).catch((error) => {
       console.log('delete error', error)
    })
  }
```